# How to decode this base64 String?

Tags: encoding, base64, decoding, string-conversion

I have a base64 String, which checks out as valid base64 in the online tools. But every single one of them fails to decode it
String is

m8WlFQM0gvk22GMp+SPuEw==

Comment: It's valid base64, but the encoded data looks like it's binary.  So the data could be from an image file, a compressed file, or some other binary format.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to identify which encoding algorithm is used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67454990/how-to-identify-which-encoding-algorithm-is-used)