# How to identify which encoding algorithm is used?

Tags: algorithm, encryption, character-encoding, base64, encode

I have a plain text and its encoded string, I wanted to know which encoder/algorithm is used to encode the string.

Plain Text: **hello world**
Encoded Text: **3MZ7hIAnvqtIqnxZJyEi+dOuJ1/myCfsbYOCsYKkZto=**

I know it has something to do with base64, but I have tried it not working for me.

Edit:
I have a notepad like exe, in which I wrote "hello world" then saved it. When I open the text file in a normal notepad it shows me "3MZ7hIAnvqtIqnxZJyEi+dOuJ1/myCfsbYOCsYKkZto=". And When I open the same file in the exe (where I wrote), it shows plain text "hello world".

Comment: It could be *literally anything.* It could be compressed. It could be encrypted in some cryptographically strong way. The algorithm might output that same string for every input.

Answer (score 6):

There are two common misunderstandings/misconceptions regarding base64 encoded strings:

1. The expectation to get readable text after decoding a base64 encoded string, along with the assumption that either the encoding is different or the base64 decoder doesn't work when the result doesn't meet the expectation
   The given string seems to be base64 encoded, it only contains characters from the base64 character set and it is correctly padded, so it's very likely a base64 encoded string. Base64 encoding is used to encode all kinds of data, but a very common use case is to encode binary data (that would not be printable or only shown as a string of 'weird`' symbols) into an easier to handle form. One typical use case is to base64 encode the result of encryption or hashing, which both create binary results.
2. The expectation that base64 decoding is the only step necessary to get back the original (e.g. plain text, password, etc.)
   As mentioned above, base64 is often used  to encode the binary result of encryption or hashing. Base64 alone is not encryption and (hopefully) never used to secure passwords or other confidential information.
   "hello world" in base64 encoding is "aGVsbG8gd29ybGQ=", and everyone can decode it with any [base64 decoder](https://www.base64decode.org/).
    The process for passwords is usually to first hash the password and then base64 encode the binary hash value. For other confidential information it's encrypting and then base64 encoding.

Having said this, the conclusion is that the given string is likely a base64 encoded hash or encrypted text.

The typical follow up question is:
 If this binary gibberish that I get from decoding is the result of encryption or hashing, how do I get the plain text?

The answer for this is: probably not at all, at least not based on the given information.

If it's a hash, there is nothing to decrypt as hashing is a one-way process.
If it's encrypted, there is no information how to decrypt this. For decryption you would need to know the encryption algorithm and the key.
And in case of hashing or encryption, the binary information usually doesn't contain any marker that marks the data as being the result of any certain hashing or encryption algorithm.
The only information I can get from the base64 encoded string (aside from the binary result) is the length. The given string is 44 characters long including one padding character, that's 43 * 6 (every base64 character encodes 6 bits) = 258 bits, so probably 256 bits. That could be, for example, a sha-256 hash, but really just a possibility.

The later added paragraph in the question about the program that stores the base64 string and retrieves the original data after reading it
makes it likely that the base64 string contains encrypted information, but that's all I can get from it.