# Unable to figure out the encoding/encryption used

Tags: encryption, access-token, urlencode, public-key-encryption

I am new to backend service and I was tracing API calls from a banking website. Normally, I have seen parameters in POST requests being encoded with base64 encoding. However, I came across a type of request where the date was encrypted with a type of encoding that I am unable to figure out.
For date: 19/12/2018 the encoding is: U2FsdGVkX1/o1qw9zIiZBHLAbGck6j15wwUZ/z/zLqw=
and for date: 18/12/2019 the encoded string is: U2FsdGVkX1/mo5+FfuqqqbUtCsdFObB8eKvyosc4b8E=

I am aware of only base64 encoding, but since I am unable to decode this with base64, it seems this is using something else. Appreciate if anyone can help and share some knowledge about the different ways in parameters can be sent to backend in a secret manner.

The encoding/encryption seems to be happening from the frontend side and I feel this could also be an encrypted string with seed sent in a separate parameter. Appreciate if someone can atleast share a list of possible algorithms that I can look into to understand the request sent and create my own requests.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to identify which encoding algorithm is used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67454990/how-to-identify-which-encoding-algorithm-is-used)

Comment: Base64 is only a way to encode/decode byte buffers so that they can be easily sent over the wire. The strings seem to be base64 encoded, but the encryption scheme is anybody's guess. But since you know the plaintext, you can mount a "known plain text attack" and possible crack the encryption if there's some vulnerability in it.

Comment: If you Base64 decode the ciphertexts, the ASCII encoding of `Salted__` is at the beginning. This indicates an encryption with [OpenSSL](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man1/enc.html) with a passphrase. If so, the `Salted__` is followed the 8 bytes salt, then the actual ciphertext.