Need help decoding this Base64 into readable text. It's from a ARG I'm participating in and it appears broken? Looking for insight
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
I have tried decoding this on multiple platforms and with my limited knowledge I'm just not sure what's wrong with it or what to look for. I'm good at absorbing information so anything would help. I appreciate anything.

It looks like binary data, and without context that's already the end of the story. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67454990/how-to-identify-which-encoding-algorithm-is-used
