gibberish result when decoding base64 content
first of all I have a very weak experience regarding encoding/decoding, and I have the following base64  - or at least ChatGPT said it's a base64 encoded! -  REST APT response ( Content-Type: application/json )
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

i tried to decode it using online tools, but I got a result of gibberish characters like below:
cJ_Qivq*1VV&60scvxfOO L Q]T2$\2%Erqz0m6m~]X H[QPTR#$e"'.Q |2&akm9/U^PYPQQKTBTA41XniiHQ>60"0;4hW[GHDJ; X< q%\k?$58-7+OT@/HI[qx!68 P]ji
what am I doing wrong or what's the right way to decode it?
Thanks.

Are you certain that the string is a complete base64 encoded string?

I don't think that is json either ... if that's what this json response is sending it really isn't json.

@ewokx i'm not completely sure, i used online identifying tools and it said base64, also ChatGPT confirmed it's base64.

@topsail the response headers said (content-type : Application / json).

Could be Base64, as it only contains character from the Base64 character set. What you call gibberish is probably just binary data, which of course looks like gibberish when you try to display it as a string. See also my related answer at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67454990/how-to-identify-which-encoding-algorithm-is-used

@jps, Thank you very much for that great answer, so, knowing that it's binary data, is there a way to know the data type/file type thats encoded?

There are some types that can be easily recognized by the first few Base64 characters, but the string you've shown is not among them. So it could be just anything, just binary data of any type of even something encrypted (but then we don't know the algorithm and key).
